# Google results of my site redirecting to Google

Tags: redirect

When I enter to my site without using a Google result, I can access without any problems, with and without www.

But, when I access throught the Google results, redirects to Google again.

This is one of my affected sites:

**Before Google Search:**

http://somesite.com/ - All OK

http://www.somesite.com/ - All OK

**Using Google Search**

https://www.google.com?q=somesite - First link refirects to Google

**After using Google results, if I access to site typing it:**

http://somesite.com/ - All OK

http://www.somesite.com/ - Redirects to Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Firebug(FireFox Add on) to see what is happening ! It will give you more clarity on what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, looks like some sites had .htaccess changed by some kind of malware.

Comment: More info: http://redleg-redleg.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/malicious-htaccess-redirect-re-written.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It has something to do with https connection.

If you are using firefox, read this: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2317787

If you are using Chrome, you can disable google redirecting search results by using this plugin: https://code.google.com/p/undirect/