# Site results redirect to Google

Tags: redirect

A site I'm working on has been hacked. The CMS (which I didn't build) was accessed and some files (e.g. "km2jk4.php.jpg") were uploaded in image fields. I have since deleted them (a week ago). Now, when I search for the site on Google, then click the result, it either:

a) simply redirects me to the Google search page

OR

b) a download dialogue appears asking me to download a zip file, with the source domain something like gb.celebritytravelnetwork.com

Clearly the site's been compromised. But if I simply type the URL in the address bar, the site loads fine. This only happens when I click through Google results.

There is no .htaccess file on the server, and this is not a virus on my computer, since many other people have reported the same thing happening, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259544/google-results-of-my-site-redirecting-to-google) is not relevant.

Any ideas please?

Thanks.

Comment: may be the attacker programmed in index page that if requests comes from domain google.com , it should redirect back to google  , the file km2jk4.php.jpg is a php shell and you should first patch the vulnerability which allowed this hack , probably checking for php extension in name of file

Comment: Thanks for your reply anshulkatta. I've checked the index.php page, there is nothing strange there. I've also deleted all the uploaded files.

Comment: u checked this link...http://blog.aw-snap.info/2012/01/malicious-htaccess-redirect-re-written.html

Comment: Yes, but as I said in my original question, there is no .htaccess file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your Source files have been changed.

Check all the files included in the index page. They might be header , footer pages.

And try using : fetch as google bot.

Comment: Thanks Sash -- however I've been through the files, including all included php files, and there's nothing there. The strange thing is that it happens only when clicking through from Google, not when I visit the site directly. I've fetched as Google using Webmaster Tools and it doesn't bring up any problems.

Comment: Try re-submitting your site via Web Master Tools . Trust me, it works! I solved something like this years ago!

Comment: I did that, as you suggested, but no joy. This is a weird one, for sure.